# How to pass a parameter to a callback method

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, callback

I have a requirement where I have to store audit information for every insert/update/delete. Info to be stored will be *update time* and *user id*.

I learned from [this tutorial](http://alexandregama.org/2014/03/23/entity-listeners-and-callback-methods-jpa/) that I can use entity listeners and callback methods like `@PrePersist`.

I know how to handle the *update time* inside the callback methods but I don't know how I can set the *userId* in entity inside the callback methods:

```
@PrePersist
private void prePersist() {
   this.updateTime = new Date();
   this.userId = ???;
}
```

How can I pass the ID of the current user to callback methods?

Comment: Are you using spring(security) by any chance?

Comment: @Forkmohit No, I am not using it.

Answer (score 3):

You can't pass any information to the callback methods with the Hibernate or JPA API directly.

But there is another common solution: [`ThreadLocal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html)

A `ThreadLocal` stores a static variable for the current running thread. And as a request is usually executed in exactly one thread, you can access that information from your callback method / listener. Some UI framework create already a `ThreadLocal` for you.

For example *JSF* provides one with `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()`. So in JSF you could call:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRemoteUser()
```

Or in *Spring* with the `RequestContextHolder`:

```
((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest().getRemoteUser()
```

If you've got no such framework you can build your own `ThreadLocal`:

```
public final class UserIdHelper {
  // You can add the static ThreadLocal to any class, just as an example
  private static final ThreadLocal<String> userIds = new ThreadLocal<>();

  public static void setCurrentUserId(String userId) {
    userIds.set(userId);
  }

  public static String getCurrentUserId() {
    return userIds.get();
  }

  public static void removeCurrentUserId() {
    userIds.remove();
  }
}
```

Now you can set the *userId* in a `Filter` or just around your JPA calls:

```
UserIdHelper.setCurrentUserId(request.getRemoteUser());
try {
  // ... Execute your JPA calls ...
} finally {
  UserIdHelper.removeCurrentUserId();
}
```

It is important to remove the *userId* in the `finally` block - otherwise a  follow up request running in the same thread could "hijack" your previous *userId*.

To access that information in your callback method:

```
@PrePersist
private void prePersist() {
  this.createdBy = UserIdHelper.getCurrentUserId();
}
```