# Pass userID in @PrePersist (@PreUpdate) method using Spring Boot and JWT

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, jwt, spring-restcontroller

I'm using JWT for authentication in my application and I need to pass the userID to the method @PrePersist in the @Entity classes. How can I do it?

This is my @RestController where pass the JwtToken:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/car")
public ResponseEntity<GenericResponse<String>> addCar(
        @RequestHeader(value = "Authorization") String token,
        @RequestParam(value = "plate") String plate) {
   // some stuff
}
```

And this is the PrePersist method in Entity classes:

```
@PrePersist
public void onPrePersist() {
    creationtime = Timestamp.from(Instant.now());
    //TODO creationuser = userID from token
}
```

Can I get the token info in Entity? What's the best way to do it?

Comment: You should consider using Spring Security and then fetch the user id from the SecurityContext

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass any information to the callback methods with the Hibernate or JPA API directly.

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33552610/how-to-pass-a-parameter-to-a-callback-method)